# How can I brew link a specific version?

Tags: homebrew

I have a few kegs of the same package in `/usr/local/Cellar/libfoo` like `/usr/local/Cellar/libfoo/1.0.1`, `/usr/local/Cellar/libfoo/HEAD` and `/usr/local/Cellar/libfoo/mycopy`

How can I brew link to a specific version?

Answer (score 333, accepted):

**[This is probably the best way as of 11.1.2022](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9832084/1574376):**

To install a specific version, e.g. postgresql 9.5 you simply run:

```
$ brew install postgresql@9.5
```

To list the available versions run a search with @:

```
$ brew search postgresql@
==> Formulae
postgresql                 postgresql@11              postgresql@13              postgresql@9.5             qt-postgresql
postgresql@10              postgresql@12              postgresql@9.4             postgresql@9.6             postgrest

==> Casks
navicat-for-postgresql
```

---

**DEPRECATED in Homebrew 2.6.0 (December 2020):**

The usage info:

```
Usage: brew switch <formula> <version>
```

Example:

```
brew switch mysql 5.5.29
```

You can find the versions installed on your system with `info`.

```
brew info mysql
```

And to see the available versions to install, you can provide a dud version number, as brew will helpfully respond with the available version numbers:

```
brew switch mysql 0
```

---

**Update (15.10.2014):**

The `brew versions` command has been removed from brew, but, if you do wish to use this command first run `brew tap homebrew/boneyard`.

The recommended way to install an old version is to install from the `homebrew/versions` repo as follows:

```
$ brew tap homebrew/versions
$ brew install mysql55
```

---

For detailed info on all the ways to install an older version of a formula read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4158763/1574376).

Comment: I followed the 15.10.2014 Update method and needed to add /usr/local/Cellar/mysql55/5.5.40/bin to my path.  Most Homebrew stuff has a symlink in /usr/local/bin to /usr/local/Cellar..., but the updated installation does not automatically add this symlink.

Comment: You still need to link the installed version and overwrite your current link by using: brew link --overwrite mysql55

Comment: Unfortunately, `brew tap homebrew/versions` now gives me an error `Error: homebrew/versions was deprecated. This tap is now empty as all its formulae were migrated`
`

Comment: Is there a way to figure out what versions are available without `versions` or just guessing-and-checking with `switch`?

Comment: versions is deprecated so I think the only way left is to find an old formula and install it from a direct URL

Comment: And now `switch` is deprecated.

Comment: That is true, my answer is no longer so good :/

Comment: This is confusing. Would it be possible to formulate a valid answer which would work for today's brew?

Comment: the solution described here worked for me in february 2024 https://nelson.cloud/how-to-install-older-versions-of-homebrew-packages/

Answer (score 49):

Sadly `brew switch` is deprecated in [Homebrew 2.6.0](https://brew.sh/2020/12/01/homebrew-2.6.0/) (December 2020)

```
$ brew switch
Error: Unknown command: switch
```

TLDR, to switch to `package` version `10`:

```sh
brew unlink package
brew link package@10
```

---

To use another version of a package, for example `node`:

- First, ensure that the specific version is installed using `brew list`. My package here is `node` (16) and `node@14`.

```
➜  ~ brew list
==> Formulae
node
node@14

➜  ~ node -v
v16.1.0
```

- Unlink the current package: `brew unlink node`.

```
➜  ~ brew unlink node
Unlinking /usr/local/Cellar/node/16.1.0... 7 symlinks removed.
```

- Link the correct version

```
➜  ~ brew link node@14
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/node@14/14.16.1_1... 3857 symlinks created.

If you need to have this software first in your PATH instead consider running:
  echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/node@14/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
➜  ~ node -v
v14.16.1
```

Comment: Instead of `unlink` then `link` you may `link` with `--overwrite` flag

Answer (score 6):

Homebrew removed `brew switch` subcommand in [Homebrew 2.6.0](https://brew.sh/2020/12/01/homebrew-2.6.0/). Get it back from [here](https://github.com/laggardkernel/homebrew-tap#external-commands).

```sh
brew tap laggardkernel/tap
brew switch --help
```

---

#### name@version formula

There's mainly two ways to switch to an old version of an app.

If it's a bigger version change. Homebrew may have created a versioned package in the repo. Like `go`, `go@1.10`, they are two different formulae, installed into two different locations.

```sh
# install the old one
brew install go@1.10

# link the executable into /usr/local/bin, or /opt/homebrew/bin
brew link --overwrite --force go@1.10
```

#### brew switch

But not every package has a versioned variant. If you just upgraded to the new version and the old one is still in your system, skip step 1, 2.

1. In this situation, search in the [homebrew-core](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/) repo and download the specific formula. e.g. [mysql 8.0.23](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/58946207e43b0e7222f6c920ef4b053e52baf76d/Formula/mysql.rb)
2. Download the **raw** file, and install from it `brew install /path/to/downloaded/mysql.rb`.
3. Now both the latest and the old 8.0.23 (same formula `mysql`) exist, switch (link out) the old version with `brew switch mysql 8.0.23`

`brew info mysql` will list all the old version still exist.

Step 1, 2 could be replaced by `brew extract`, but that requires user maintain its own tap. I won't cover it here, just search it if you're interested.

Comment: This worked nicely with latest version of brew. The accepted answer seems to be outdated.

Answer (score 4):

If you have installed, for example, php 5.4 it could be switched in the following way to php 5.5:

```
$ php --version
PHP 5.4.32 (cli) (built: Aug 26 2014 15:14:01) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies

$ brew unlink php54

$ brew switch php55 5.5.16

$ php --version
PHP 5.5.16 (cli) (built: Sep  9 2014 14:27:18) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
```

Answer (score 4):

`brew switch libfoo mycopy`

You can use `brew switch` to switch between versions of the same package, if it's installed as versioned subdirectories under `Cellar/<packagename>/`

This will list versions installed ( for example I had `Cellar/sdl2/2.0.3`, I've compiled into `Cellar/sdl2/2.0.4`)

```
brew info sdl2
```

Then to switch between them

```
brew switch sdl2 2.0.4
brew info
```

Info now shows `*` next to the 2.0.4

To install under `Cellar/<packagename>/<version>` from source you can do for example

```
cd ~/somewhere/src/foo-2.0.4
./configure --prefix $(brew --Cellar)/foo/2.0.4
make
```

check where it gets installed with

```
make install -n
```

if all looks correct

```
make install
```

Then from `cd $(brew --Cellar)` do the switch between version.

I'm using `brew version 0.9.5`

Answer (score 3):

In case `brew switch` produces an error (in this example trying to switch to node version 14):

```
> brew switch node 14
Error: Calling `brew switch` is disabled! Use `brew link` @-versioned formulae instead.
```

The correct way switching versions would be :

```
> brew link --overwrite node@14
```

Answer (score -2):

if @simon's answer is not working in some of the mac's please follow the below process.

If you have already installed swiftgen using the following commands:

$ `brew update`
$ `brew install swiftgen`

then follow the steps below in order to run swiftgen with older version.

Step 1: `brew uninstall swiftgen`
Step 2: Navigate to: https://github.com/SwiftGen/SwiftGen/releases
and download the swiftgen with version: swiftgen-4.2.0.zip.

Unzip the package in any of the directories.

Step 3:
Execute the following in a terminal:

```
$ mkdir -p ~/dependencies/swiftgen
$ cp -R ~/<your_directory_name>/swiftgen-4.2.0/ ~/dependencies/swiftgen
$ cd /usr/local/bin
$ ln -s ~/dependencies/swiftgen/bin/swiftgen swiftgen
$ mkdir ~/Library/Application\ Support/SwiftGen
$ ln -s ~/dependencies/swiftgen/templates/ ~/Library/Application\ Support/SwiftGen/

$ swiftgen --version
```

You should get: SwiftGen v0.0 (Stencil v0.8.0, StencilSwiftKit v1.0.0, SwiftGenKit v1.0.1)

[image]

Comment: Downvoted as this answer doesn't answer the authors question.