# Can I have gcc/g++ on MacOS X 10.11 pointing to the ACTUAL gcc/g++?

Tags: c++, macos, c++11, gcc, g++

This is really annoying. For some reason, on MacOS X 10.11 (probably also on previous versions) there are `gcc` and `g++` commands (in `/usr/bin`, they are not aliases or so) which, when executed with the `-v` argument, give:

```
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.2.0
Thread model: posix
```

So it looks like they actually execute the clang and clang++ compilers by apple. Now, I really need my computer to execute gcc and g++ when I invoke those commands, both from the terminal and through makefiles.

The reasons for this are two:

1. I like to have my computer do what I ask it to do.
2. Apparently clang++ compiles stuff using a different c++ standard library from g++, and this is causing me problems when I compile and link my stuff with `g++-5` (the ACTUAL g++, installed via homebrew) against CppUnit.

Does anybody know what is the best way to have `gcc` and `g++` actually call gcc and g++?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Include in your PATH, before `/usr/bin`, a directory that contains a symbolic link named `gcc` pointing to `/…/bin/gcc-5`.

The latest Mac OS X does not let you change `/usr`, from what I hear, so this conservative solution is the only one available.

> when I invoke those commands, both from the terminal and through makefiles.

If you adjust your PATH variable in your `.profile`, both these cases will be covered.

Comment: `/opt/local/bin` sounds like MacPorts, which OP may not have installed/used.

Comment: @ThomasDickey Ah, yes, I thought the OP had mentioned MacPorts in the question but it was actually homebrew.

Comment: yes (I'll stick with MacPorts, since *I* use `/usr/local`).  By the way, only parts of `/usr` are "protected" (it seems they made a special exception for `/usr/local`).  I noticed this because they quarantined my build-tree (would be nice if they'd thought it through, and made the feature configurable).

Answer (score 1):

Apple does not actually provide `gcc` or `g++`, although (perhaps only misguided) they make aliases to pretend that `clang` is the same.

You can *install* `gcc` and `g++` with [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/) (also with [homebrew](http://brew.sh/)).  I use MacPorts, which puts its executables in `/opt/local/bin`.

With MacPorts, I see these currently-available *ports* (programs that have to be compiled to work on one's machine), using this command

```
port list |grep gcc

gcc410                         @5-20140817     lang/gcc410 
gcc43                          @4.3.6          lang/gcc43 
gcc44                          @4.4.7          lang/gcc44 
gcc45                          @4.5.4          lang/gcc45 
gcc46                          @4.6.4          lang/gcc46 
gcc47                          @4.7.4          lang/gcc47 
gcc48                          @4.8.5          lang/gcc48 
gcc49                          @4.9.3          lang/gcc49
gcc5                           @5.2.0          lang/gcc5
gcc6                           @6-20151129     lang/gcc6
gccxml-devel                   @20150423       lang/gccxml-devel
gcc_select                     @0.1            sysutils/gcc_select
gccmakedep                     @1.0.3          x11/gccmakedep
```

According to its webpage, `brew` would do something similar, but install into `/usr/local/bin`.

When I installed MacPorts, its installer updated my `~/.profile`, adding this to update `PATH`:

```
# MacPorts Installer addition on 2015-10-03_at_14:17:30: adding an appropriate PATH variable for use with MacPorts.
export PATH="/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH"
# Finished adapting your PATH environment variable for use with MacPorts.
```

Each of those ports from MacPorts installs `gcc` with a different name, and the `port` script has a feature `select` which establishes a symbolic link, e.g., from `gcc` to `gcc49`.  `brew` has something similar.  According to [How can I brew link a specific version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13477363/how-can-i-brew-link-a-specific-version), you would use

```
brew switch gcc-package-name package-version
```

e.g., (guessing at a valid name)

```
brew switch gcc 4.9
```

Comment: The OP says they already installed gcc through homebrew. Neither installing through homebrew nor installing through MacPorts alone makes `gcc` actually call GCC, which is the OP's question, because it is installed with a name like `gcc-mp-5` or `gcc-5`.